# Correct way of modifying ROS classes? (do I have to edit installed headers directly?)

Tags: ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, header, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Goal:** Add a new member function in *callback_queue.cpp* from *roscpp* (*ros_comm* stack)

**Problem:** *make* error "no member function declared in class ‘ros::CallbackQueue’"

**Details:**
To get the roscpp source, I followed the instructions to build from source (http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source).

I added my new member function in
/home/xyz/ros-underlay/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp
and declared it in
/home/xyz/ros-underlay/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/callback_queue.h

However, when performing (in /home/xyz/ros-underlay/build)

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte
make -j8
```

I get the error

```
    /home/xyz/ros-underlay/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp:75:29:
error: no ‘void ros::CallbackQueue::my_new_func()’ member function declared
in class ‘ros::CallbackQueue’
```

I can get rid of this error by editing the already installed header file (/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/callback_queue.h) and declaring the new member function there. However I guess it's not the recommended approach to work directly on the installed header files, instead of those in /home/xyz/ros_underlay (?).

-> **So my question is what is the correct approach when I want to perform some edits in ROS files like callback_queue.cpp?** Should I somehow tell *make* (or CMakelists.txt) to use the headers in /home/xyz/ros-underlay/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38175/correct-way-of-modifying-ros-classes?-(do-i-have-to-edit-installed-headers-directly?)/) by [rob20](https://answers.ros.org/users/2790/rob20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-07-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-08**:
I'm somewhat surprised make isn't already using the headers that go along with the sources you configured as opposed to the ones in /opt/ros ... Is catkin/cmake setting the include directories to /opt/ros (or otherwise your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH) and putting those before the headers in your source build?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-08**:
Maybe you could try make -j1 VERBOSE=1 to get more verbose output and include the make line for callback_queue.cpp here so we can take a look at the include paths that the compiler is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks joq, but that did not solve the issue: I still have to edit the *installed* header file (as opposed to the header file in the source tree), and I don't think that's a good way (?). The only thing that using -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX changed was that the installation is now in my home directory instead of /opt/ros/fuerte.

Details:

According to your suggestion, I created a new install subdir /home/xyz/ros-underlay/install, and then, from /home/xyz/ros-underlay, called

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install
make -j8
sudo make install
```

For the first *sudo make install* I could run make to have my modified callback_queue compiled. But for subsequent changes, I get the same *make* error as in my original question, and I can only get rid of it by editing the installed header file in /home/xyz/ros-underlay/install, instead of the "source" version in /home/xyz/ros-underlay/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros.

P.S. I wanted to post this as a comment to your answer, but there was no comment field (I only see comment fields under my own posts so far).

---

Originally posted by [rob20](https://answers.ros.org/users/2790/rob20/) with karma: 36 on 2012-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-08**:
This is too long to be a comment. You should update your original question to include this additional information. That's also better than using an answer for something too long for a comment so that it doesn't get re-ordered in the future as answers get sorted by votes/date/etc